# Калькулятор в tkinter. Не работает вывод ответа

Tags: python, tkinter

Я прошу прощения за некорректно построенный вопрос. Я хотел бы спросить о том, что не так в написанной иной программе, вернее сказать почему работа с функцией plus(event) не происходит. Я начал изучать pyеhon использую одну книгу и вот там затронули работу с библиотекой tkinter, смотря на это, я решил , чтобы лучше разобраться в этом, написать простой калькулятор, в котором 1 grid и 2 drid получают числа от пользователя , далее происходит выбор функции, увы я расписал только plus, и ответ должен был выводиться в строке ответ. Помогите пожалуйста, я с этой задачей сижу уже 3тий день.

```
from tkinter import *

g = Tk()
global entr 
g.title('calculator')
gt = Frame(g)
gt.pack()
entr = {}

tg= Label(gt,text="1 число:")
tg.grid(row=0, column=0)
one = Entry(gt)
one.grid(row=0, column=1)

t= Label(gt,text="2 число:")
t.grid(row=1, column=0)
two = Entry(gt)
two.grid(row=1, column=1)

tgf= Label(gt,text="Ответ:")
tgf.grid(row=2, column=0)
ty = Entry(gt)
ty.grid(row=2, column=1)

def makeWidgets():
    Button(g, text="сложить", font='defaultgui', command=plus).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(g, text="вычесть",font='defaultgui').pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(g, text="умножить", font='defaultgui').pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(g, text="разделить", font='defaultgui').pack(side=LEFT)



def plus():
    x = one.get() 
    y = two.get()
    y1 = (float(y))
    x1 = (float(x))
    o = x1 + y1
    tgf = Label(gt,text = o)
    return o
g = makeWidgets()
mainloop()
```

Comment: почему вы не читаете комментарии? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Я прочитал несколько раз, и я не понимаю, что вы хотите, чтобы я сделал

Comment: как минимум не создавать второй раз точно такой же вопрос. Переменные в одной функии не имеют ни малейшего отношения к другим переменным, даже если одинаково называются. Это подсказка

Comment: Второй вопрос был похожим, но не таким. А по поводу работы с tkinter  я уже пересмотрел сотни видео уроков и десятки форумов в поисках моей оплошности, к сожалению я так и не понял где я ошибся (